# How to make my query for one id work for many ids

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
  id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id  INTEGER REFERENCES nodes(id),
  trashed_at timestamptz
)
```

I have this query `nodes_trash_node(node_id INTEGER)`:

```
UPDATE nodes SET
  trashed_at = now()
WHERE nodes.id = node_id
OR nodes.id IN (SELECT id FROM nodes_descendants(node_id))
RETURNING *
```

The `nodes_descendants` function operates on an adjacency list structure and looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nodes_descendants(node_id INTEGER, depth INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER) AS $$
  WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT id, array[node_id]::integer[] as ancestors
    FROM   nodes
    WHERE  parent_id = node_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nodes.id, tree.ancestors || nodes.parent_id
    FROM   nodes, tree
    WHERE  nodes.parent_id = tree.id
    AND    (depth = 0 OR cardinality(tree.ancestors) < depth)
  )
  SELECT id FROM tree;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

(taken from [here](https://schinckel.net/2014/11/27/postgres-tree-shootout-part-2%3A-adjacency-list-using-ctes/)).

However I'd now like to convert my query to take a list of `node_id`s, but I'm struggling to find the correct syntax.  Something like:

```
UPDATE nodes SET
  trashed_at = now()
WHERE nodes.id = ANY(node_ids)
OR nodes.id IN (???)
RETURNING *
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I'd like to now select many 'root' `node_id`s and all their descendants.  For the example use case: select many files and folders and move to the trash at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is straight-forward if you do not use a function actually.

BTW, I have changed it to a proper `INNER JOIN`.
Please do not use tables products (i.e. cross joins) followed by `WHERE` as you will mistakenly skip it someday.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT  id
    FROM   nodes
    WHERE  <Type your condition here>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nodes.id
    FROM   nodes
    JOIN tree ON nodes.parent_id = tree.id
)
UPDATE nodes SET
  trashed_at = now()
WHERE nodes.id IN (SELECT id from Tree)
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will study your changes to the CTE.  However I think you misunderstand the question: I would like to go from one root node_id and it's descendants to many root node_ids and all their descendants

Comment: if you replace my `<Type your condition here>` by a condition that returns many root nodes, won't that do exactly what you described?

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: I like that you have greatly simplified the query using JOIN, but after experimenting with it, it's unclear how I can implement a depth restriction now.

Comment: The 'cross joins' are recommended in the Postgres docs for this use case [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-with.html) (search for depth).  The function descendants (and its evil twin ancestors) are very specific to traversing the adjacency list, so unless you have a nice technique for this, I'll stick with it.. thanks for showing me where I need to put my ANY query though!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know if this is right or not without the larger context of where these updates are running.  Presumably it's within a procedure/function or through an application?

Either way, I think your final syntax was fine -- it's just you need to ensure the datatype you pass is an array:

```
update nodes
set trashed_at = now()
where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Is essentially the same functionally as:

```
update nodes
set trashed_at = now()
where id = any(array[1, 2, 3]);
```

So, back to your original statement:

```
UPDATE nodes SET
  trashed_at = now()
WHERE nodes.id = ANY(node_ids)
OR nodes.id IN (???)
RETURNING *
```

I think you can simplify this to:

```
UPDATE nodes SET
  trashed_at = now()
WHERE nodes.id = ANY(node_ids)
RETURNING *
```

Just be sure `node_ids` is an array of 64-bit integers.

So, assuming this was within a procedure, these are some examples:

```
DECLARE
  node_ids bigint[];
BEGIN

  node_ids := array[1, 2, 3, 4];

  -- or perhaps

  select array_agg (bar)
  into node_ids
  from foo
  where baz = x;

  UPDATE nodes
  SET trashed_at = now()
  WHERE nodes.id = ANY(node_ids)
  RETURNING *;
END;
```

IMO it's always been a struggle to pass an in-list as a parameters, but with PostgreSQL arrays it's not only possible but quite straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I think there's a confusion: my examples above will already allow me to set the 'trashed_at' column of a node and its descendants, but now I would like to be able to select many nodes and all their descendants

Comment: Aah, I see... yes, that is very different.  I looked at the answer from @lau, and it appears to be what you need -- and accomplishes it without the function.